# Ubuntu Server Simple Password protected share

Tags: server, samba

I have 3 samba shares and wamt to proptect them, with a password.They are all located in the /media folder with 777 rights. And they work, until i try to password protect them. I have searched for almost 2 hours and nothing works. it either comes up with the login-promt and then, when i ttry to accsess it, windows throws an unknown error. I just want them password protected, with User: user-xxx and Password: xxxxxxx

All help is welcome :(

By the way: Running latest ubuntu-server and samba. Tried reinstalling of samba, but it doesnt work.

My smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password


[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browsable = no
read only = no
create mode = 0750

[nas]
path = /media/storage/
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = werner-web
printable = no
guest ok = yes
[kodi]
path = /media/kodi/
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = KODI
printable = no
guest ok = yes
[backup]
path = /media/backup/
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = werner-web
printable = no
guest ok = yes
```

Comment: What is missing from your post is if you added the user to the samba password database: `sudo smbpasswd -a some-user-name`

Comment: did it.... But it still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password

[nas]
path = /media/storage/
public = no
writable = yes
comment = werner-web
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
[kodi]
path = /media/kodi/
public = no
writable = yes
comment = PLEX
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
[backup]
path = /media/backup/winbackup
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = werner-web
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
[Private-Backups]
path = /media/backup
public = no
writable = yes
comment = Closed-Backup
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
[ROM]
path = /media/backup/ROM
public = yes
writable = no
comment = ROM
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
```

by the way: I am an idiot